# How do i enable App install tracking in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, swift3, idfa

I have integrated pod 'GoogleIDFASupport' in my iOS application by referring

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMhZo.png)

I am unable to find where to put this code in my project

```
// Enable IDFA collection.
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Add it after initialization of the tracker:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/display-features